# Let a random experiment be the cast of a pair of unbiased 6-sided dice and let X=the smaller of the outcomes?

Tags: probability

Let a random experiment be the cast of a pair of unbiased 6-sided dice and let X=the smaller of the outcomes?

a. With reasonable assumptions find the p.m.f. of X. 
b. Let Y equal the range of the two outcomes, i.e., the absolute value of the difference of the largest and the smallest outcomes. Determine the p.m.f. g(y) of Y for y = 0,1,2,3,4,5.

I completed question (A) but i can't find out question b. 
So far I have this drawn out:
y=0,1,2,3,4,5

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 
01 11 12 13 14 15
02 21 22 23 24 25
03 31 32 33 34 35
04 41 42 43 44 45
05 51 52 53 54 55
```

is this the right direction for b? Please explain in detail. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the results of the dice:
$$\begin{array}{r|cccccc} Y=|A\!-\!B|
     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6
\\ \hline
   1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3
\\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2
\\ 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1
\\ 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}$$

Now express this as a PMF